# Is "put it in picture" a phrase?

Tags: phrases

I don't know if I'm going crazy or confusing this phrase for another, but in my head something like:

> Let me put it in picture for you

Is a phrase that equates to

> Let me explain it to you/Let me give some context for you

However after searching online for a bit, I couldn't find any instances of it mentioned anywhere.

Comment: I've heard "Let me paint a picture for you." is it possible that this is what you confused it with? http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/paint+a+picture

Comment: OR "Let me put you in the picture".

Comment: @StoneyB Both of those are valid alternatives, but it has me wondering. Does "in picture" have any significance? That's the part that's stuck in my head.

Comment: @AR7 "in *the* picture" means approximately "aware of the circumstances"

Comment: @StoneyB lol so I just completely made it up. Thank you :D

Comment: Pictures as a metaphor for awareness/knowledge seems fairly prevalent in English: see phrases such as "the big picture".

Comment: @JohnClifford Could you elaborate on that idea, say, to the tune of 1,000 words?

Comment: @DanBron I could, but I don't think it would be worth it.

Comment: @JohnClifford How about just a picture then? ;)

Comment: @DanBron lol saw that coming. http://i.imgur.com/K2xmAju.jpg

Comment: @DanBron Question is, which of us is going to post an answer? ;)

Comment: @StoneyB  To me, more versed in the British idiom, this whole post seems to conflate two different expressions. *To put someone in the picture* usually means simply to inform them of something. *Make sure you put Geoff in the picture about the disappearance of Harold's wife, before you introduce the two of them*. But *let me explain the big(ger)/full picture* usually means you intend to add some wider context to what the listener already knows.

Comment: "*Let me draw you a diagram*..."

Comment: "Red hopping potato" Is a phrase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me [*put it in a picture*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=put+it+in+a+picture&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cput%20it%20in%20a%20picture%3B%2Cc0) with a Google ngram
[image: Put it in a picture ngram]

Answer (score 2):

You'll need an article.  With the ***indefinite article***, the phrase makes a straightforward metaphor, meaning to explain by visual means.  Consider this [website](http://www.desiringgod.org/messages/exalting-jesus-so-the-spirit-falls) about Christian apologetics:

> Jesus **put it in *a* picture**. He compares the freedom of the Spirit
>   to the freedom of the wind. In John 3:8 he says, "The wind blows where
>   it wills, and you hear the sound of it, but you do not know whence it
>   comes or whither it goes; so is every one who is born of the Spirit."

The literal meaning also appears in discussion of cinema.  With the ***definite article***, you can also get a direct metaphorical usage:

From *Connecting with Your Asperger Partner: Negotiating the Maze of Intimacy* by Louise Weston:

> At the moment, communication between you and your Aspie resembles a
>   jigsaw puzzle. I't s a very gradual process of trial and error, where
>   you try finding ways to fit the pieces together.  You may find one
>   piece at a time and **put it in *the* picture**.

But the object of *put* is more often the ***second person pronoun***, giving you an idiomatic phrase meaning to explain an entire situation in full context to someone.  From [*... My Thanks to You!*](https://books.google.com/books?id=nVj_BwAAQBAJ&pg=PT80&dq=%22put%20you%20in%20the%20picture%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjgidLi9rvLAhWFbSYKHfSmCdAQ6AEIPjAF#v=onepage&q=%22put%20you%20in%20the%20picture%22&f=false) by Jack Coppard:

> “Make a cup of tea, Eddie will be in any minute now, then I'll **put**
>   ***you*** **in the picture**.” Eddie came bustling in on excitement level ten,
>   ready to rock and roll. I carefully explained the whole story to
>   Michael, ....